# Can I build instant maps from kinect

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, scan, gmapping, 2d-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all

ROS is really a great stranger to me.

I am using Xbox360, ROS Kinetic, Ubuntu16.04 LTS

I am doing a  project in which the robot should produce the map as it goes through an unknown environment. Is it possible to do so. As of now I only know the method of using .bag files i.e., hector_slam but I have a problem there also. Any way I have posted a question regarding that already.

Can anyone suggest me a way how to do the mapping instantly only using kinect. I mean I  can't provide /tf  data from the robot. But, I want to get the map without any thing like bag file.

Sorry for poor English. Hope you all understand the question.

**UPDATE**

I HAVE CLONED THE RTab PACKAGE INTO MY CATKIN WORK SPACE. AND THEN I AM DOING CATKIN_MAKE. I HAVE THIS ERROR

CMake Error at rtabmap_ros/CMakeLists.txt:21 (find_package):
By not providing "FindRTABMap.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "RTABMap", but
CMake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "RTABMap"
(requested version 0.14.0) with any of the following names:

```
RTABMapConfig.cmake
rtabmap-config.cmake
```

Add the installation prefix of "RTABMap" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"RTABMap_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
"RTABMap" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
been installed.

Thank you in advance....

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279765/can-i-build-instant-maps-from-kinect/) by [NAGALLA DEEPAK](https://answers.ros.org/users/33107/nagalla-deepak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2018-01-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-01-15**:
You only build packages from source if you *really* need to in my opinion! Since there are binary packages available for this you can install it with a single line as it says at the top of the installation guide. Keep it simple.

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-rtabmap-ros
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are two well developed ROS systems for doing exactly what you want. [RTAB-Map](http://introlab.github.io/rtabmap/) is the one we prefer in our lab, but the alternative [rgbslam](http://wiki.ros.org/rgbdslam) is also very good and depending on your exact use case may be a better solution.

Both of these systems are designed specifically for RGB-D sensors such as the Kinect, and have fairly good setup guides.

Hope this helps.

**Update:** You're trying to do 2D mapping with a 3D sensor, how is the robot moving? If it's driving over a flat floor and will not tilt, drive up ramps etc then you can extract a 2D slice from the kinect point cloud and convert it to a (mock) laser scan. If you robot will be driving in a 3D fasion then 2D mapping is not appropriate and you'll have to build a 3D map.

I think the documentation of rgbdslam is not up-to date. We've made it work on kinetic without any problems.

Out of interest why is a 3D map not suitable to your needs?

**Update:** Theoretically 3D mapping is more complicated, but since the software has already been made for you, and you're using a 3D sensor it will be easier for you to implement 3D than converting your sensor to 2D.

You can find the ROS installation instructions to [RTAB map here](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros#rtabmap_ros-) and there are good set of tutorials, including [this one here](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/HandHeldMapping) which describes how to do mapping with several sensors including the kinect you're working with.

Hope this gets you started.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NAGALLA DEEPAK](https://answers.ros.org/users/33107/nagalla-deepak/) on 2018-01-14**:
Thanks for your response, I want to do 2D_mapping. Moreover rgbslam you stated is for future and indigo. But I am using Kinetic.

**Comment by [NAGALLA DEEPAK](https://answers.ros.org/users/33107/nagalla-deepak/) on 2018-01-14**:
I thought 3D mapping is more complex than 2D. So I opted for 2D. Could you explain me how you did 3D mapping using kinect. I mean steps to install RTAB and  any further information regarding this is welcome

**Comment by [NAGALLA DEEPAK](https://answers.ros.org/users/33107/nagalla-deepak/) on 2018-01-14**:
please help me with the installation. I am getting this error while doing catkin_make. Please see  the question for update about these errors

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2018-01-15**:
If you still want to get rtabmap built from source, follow carefully the steps [here](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros#build-from-source) (in particular 0-2-3). rtabmap and rtabmap_ros should be cloned from the same branch name to be compatible.

**Comment by [Dox](https://answers.ros.org/users/34329/dox/) on 2018-03-27**:
Hi! Are there any other options that would be worth trying out for 3D mapping and autonomous navigation using RGB-D sensors like Kinect, Astra, PrimeSense? What about using KinFu within ROS? Thanks.

**Comment by [NAGALLA DEEPAK](https://answers.ros.org/users/33107/nagalla-deepak/) on 2018-03-27**:
I have not been so deep into 3D mapping. But I gave it a try. I tried RGB-D slam with kinect and it worked great. But I think there is some distortion in the map and we have to adjust some parameters. I have read that there are some issues with Kinfu [here](http://unanancyowen.com/en/pcl-fusion/).